# Function calling using Google's VextexAI Java Client (google-cloud-vertexai:0.1.0) is not possible?

Tags: java, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've been playing around with the Google's new Gemini Model through Vextex AI using Java.
It seems like the GenerativeModel class doesn't allow using the Tool object in order to use the function calling functionality.
The only option would be to use the method:

```
private ResponseStream<GenerateContentResponse> generateContentStream(Builder requestBuilder)
```

But unfortunately thats a private method. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Paulo Taylor, have you checked this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/quickstart-multimodal#send-request) ? Please let me know if this is helpful for you.

Comment: @SushmaJeerahalli thanks but it's not really helpful